# what does "tapping into their resentment" mean in the following passage?

Tags: meaning

> He was a dreamer with a common touch and enormous ambition. He maintained an almost visceral connection with the poor, **tapping into their resentments**, while strutting like the strong man in a caudillo novel. His followers called him Comandante.

Does it mean **making them outraged** or **using their anger**?

Answer (score 2):

To "tap into" something means *to use it as a resource*. Think of a faucet, which can also be called a tap. It is a way of getting a resource (eg water) on demand. We often refer to things being "on tap", or "tapping into" things in a figurative way.

It is difficult to get the full meaning of your quotation without the wider context, but it seems to be talking about someone with great influence over common people. "Tapping into their resentments" suggests that he knew the things that ordinary people were angry about, and used that to his advantage - perhaps agreeing with them in order to make allies, or making promises to fix things they were angry about. Politicians are often accused of doing this.

Comment: Thank you, now I understood